# refresh combobox items at runtime wpf

Tags: wpf, combobox

I want a comboBox containing open serial ports as items. But it updates automatically when serial ports modify.

My approach is this:

1. create in Xaml a comboBox like this:

   ```
   <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,35,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147" ContextMenuOpening="comboBox1_ContextMenuOpening" />
   ```
2. create a method that loops trough ports and adds them to comboBox:

   ```
   public string[] portsManual;

   public void adaugaPorturi()
   {
       if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0)
       {
           comboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
       }
       comboBox1.Items.Add("Select port");
       comboBox1.SelectedItem = "Select port";
       portsManual = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
       foreach (string port in portsManual)
       {
           comboBox1.Items.Add(port);
       }
       comboBox1.Items.Refresh();
       Array.Clear(portsManual, 0, portsManual.Length);
   }
   ```
3. call this method at window.load (so it can have something in it - the ports opened right then) and call it at ContextMenuOpening event (whenever I click the comboBox to select an item - a port, to refresh)

Note: I am clearing the comboBox items (if any) at start, and the same for the string array, but it doesnt update, the items are still the ones at first run of this method!

I have tried: ObservableCollection, strings, and arrays with no luck. The most info I have found on this site. I am thinking that because are only a few ports, I don't really need a Collection or List. I just add items directly.

BTW, can an admin edit this post? I am not sure if text format is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you should probably be using MVVM and data binding rather than querying serial ports directly from your view's code-behind.

Secondly, it seems like you're using the wrong event, if you want it to refresh everytime the menu opens, you should use the DropDownOpened event

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,35,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147" DropDownOpened="comboBox1_DropDownOpened" />
```

And try this in your code-behind

```
public void InitPorts()
{
    RefreshPorts();
    comboBox1.SelectedItem = "Select port";
}
public void RefreshPorts()
{
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Select port");
    foreach (var port in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        comboBox1.Items.Add(port);
}
private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    InitPorts();
}
private void ComboBox1_OnDropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RefreshPorts();
}
```

Comment: Ty, it works! Thanks! It seems that I was using the wrong event all the time, and I've been trying lots of implementations with lists and collections and still didn't worked because of this. Thanks alot.